# Populate table with username of other followed users

Tags: swift, parse-platform

```
class FollowingTableTableViewController: UITableViewController {

let usernames = NSMutableArray()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getUsernames()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

func getUsernames() {

    var user1 = PFUser.currentUser()
    var findUsernames:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "FollowRequests")
    findUsernames.whereKey("from", equalTo: user1!)
    findUsernames.includeKey("to")

    findUsernames.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        var myObjects = objects as! [PFObject]

        //Solve this part. Need to get all of the users from the "to" field in FollowRequests.

        //If No error
        if (error == nil) {
            for myObjects in objects! {
                var user2 = PFUser()
                user2.objectForKey("to")
                self.usernames.addObject(user2.username!)
                println(user2.username)
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.usernames.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    -> UITableViewCell {
        let item: AnyObject = self.usernames[indexPath.row]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel!.text = (usernames[indexPath.row] as! String)
        return cell
}
```

I keep getting the fatal error:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

What do I need to do?

Hoping to find where I messed up.

Comment: are try to find the query using the currentUser name or ID

Comment: Usually Xcode will highlight the line that caused the error, can you share that as well?

Comment: query is by username

Comment: ok did you see my suggestion

Comment: Yup looking into it right now.

Comment: I put your correction in and now I get: Could not cast value of type 'PFUser' (0x1faa70) to 'NSString' (0x333620b0) The exception breakpoint is here:             var myObjects = objects as! [PFObject]

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of ? in your code:

First: are you trying to query using the currentUser(username ) or (objectID)

Second: in the findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock method 
 you need to check if there is an error first then convert the array of any object to PFObject

```
if error  == nil{
if let objects = objects as! [PFObject]{
   for oneSpecificObject in objects{
     var data = oneSpecificObject["to"] as! String  
      self.usernames.addObject(data)
     }
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

}

Third: In the cellForRowAtIndexPath method 
why you have that extra line

```
let item: AnyObject = self.usernames[indexPath.row]
```

//review carefully your code then if you still have problem let me know.